# How to determine ARM function is written in thumb or not

Tags: assembly, arm, self-modifying

I'm writing hooker code which patch ARM function prologue to do it. Since ARM can run in two mode, Hooker have to choose right opcode (thumb or not) to patch prologue.

How can I make it to determine patching target is using thumb or 32-bit ARM instruction?

Comment: Do you have the _linker-generated_ symbol address for the function? If so, nothing stops you doing the exact same thing the core does; look at the LSB of the branch target. Otherwise, "it depends" and you'll need to provide rather more detail.

Comment: Make sure your hooker code doesn't catch a virus.  It will spread every where.  It is hard to understand things with multiple meanings.  You may put an instruction that will fault instead in both modes.  On first execution, the trap handler will inspect the mode and insert the correct **hook** code for that mode.  This is advantageous as it *lazy* and some faults may never be encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was working in linux kernel. After looking around for kprobe() code, I found CONFIG_THUMB2_KERNEL macro.

Since it is not generic solution, I can solve my problem with that macro to decide opcode to patch in compile time.